# jquery mobile checking multiselect slow

Tags: performance, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have JQM search application, there is Country multiselect (about 200 items), i get it takes a while to load, but item checking also takes loong (more than second on mid-class phone).

I tried different JQM library versions witout any success.

Is there any way to speed it up?

Here is firefox profile from android device (remote debugging):
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=03814094338551864106
and here from chrome:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=83838903265708935143

EDIT: 
JSFiddle:
`<option data-id="000" value="188">Country 188</option> ...`http://jsfiddle.net/zLjxxmgz/4/

Comment: How about showing us your markup and code? Even better, create a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue as well.

Comment: Try this function from pagecreate -> 
function optimizeSpeed() {
    var hoverDelay = $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 0;

    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
    $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
}. If it helped, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: how is anyone going to know why you have a bottleneck in your app without seeing a demo. post code in your question and/or create a demo here -- http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @ezanker Ok, i added a JSFiddle

Comment: Reset code should be: $("#select-choice").val([]).selectmenu('refresh', true);

Comment: @ezanker That is not my problem but thanks, it will come handy :)